# Azure Synapse Creating random duplicate data while inserting from staging to final table

Tags: sql, insert, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

I have simple task at hand. I have close to 200 unique million records seating in a staging table on Azure Synapse. The task is to run an insert statement to insert data into final table. Sounds simple, but here is the problem I am running into for which I am scratching my head. Every time I execute insert random rows are duplicated in final table. I have checked multiple times that staging table has all unique values based on combination of composite key of 3 columns.

Has anyone ran into this weird issue before? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you share sample input and expected output?

Comment: Hi Pratik! Basically the input to insert statement is unique 200 million records and output should be unique 200 million records in final table. Here is the query

insert INTO persistent.tableX(abc, xyz, fgh, hgj)
select abc, xyz, fgh, hgj from staging.tableX

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simple **INSERT** statement, I Tried using a **MERGE** statement to insert data into the final table.
in this way it will allow you how to handle duplicate rows.

For example I have created a table **staging_table_copy**

```
create TABLE staging_table_copy (
id INT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
age INT NOT NULL,
);
```

[image]
[image]
I have created the **Target table** as

```
CREATE TABLE Final_table (
   id INT NOT NULL,
   name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   age INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id, name, age)
);
```

As you can see there are duplicate values in this table.

```
select name, count(Name) as counts
from final_table
group by name
having count(name)>1
```

[image]
[image]

Now in the Next step I am **TRUNCATING** the Final_table.
And will **INSERT** the Data from the staging_table_copy.
with the help of **MERGE** statement.
[image]

```
MERGE final_table AS t
USING staging_table_copy AS s
ON t.id = s.id AND t.name = s.name AND t.age = s.age
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
   INSERT (id, name, age)
   VALUES (s.id, s.name, s.age);
```

[image]
[image]
Verifiing the Duplicates too
[image]